# Is hidden not working on image views in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
@IBOutlet weak var allStocksSelected: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var shortStocksSelected: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var longStocksSelected: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var myStocksTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myStocksTableView.delegate = self
    myStocksTableView.dataSource = self
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.shortStocksSelected.isHidden = true
    self.longStocksSelected.isHidden = true
    self.allStocksSelected.isHidden = true
}

@IBAction func allStocksButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print("ALL!")
    self.stockTypeChanged(stockType: allStocksSelected)
}

@IBAction func shortStocksButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print("SHORT!")
    self.stockTypeChanged(stockType: shortStocksSelected)
}

@IBAction func longStocksButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print("LONG!")
    self.longStocksSelected.isHidden = false
    self.shortStocksSelected.isHidden = true
    self.allStocksSelected.isHidden = true
   //stockTypeChanged(stockType: longStocksSelected)
}

@IBAction func addNewStockButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

}

@IBAction func signOutButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

}

private func stockTypeChanged(stockType: UIImageView) {
    let stockTypes: [UIImageView] = [allStocksSelected, shortStocksSelected, longStocksSelected]
    for (stock) in stockTypes {
        if (stock == stockType) {
            stock.isHidden = false
        } else {
            stock.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

As shown from my code above, I am basically just trying to hide and show certain image views when buttons are pressed.

I am 100% sure that all of the buttons actions and IB outlets are properly connected, yet the image views are still not hiding and showing, and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fine. Check the properties inside Interface Builder, you might have an alpha value set to zero.

Comment: Are those image views hiding initially or not?

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine. So please check your connection and also check your tableView not cover the image view.

Answer (score -1):

I was running into this same issue. Placing your `isHidden` code to execute on the main thread should solve the problem.

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {

}
```